# How to keep containers running?

Tags: docker, docker-image

I have an old rpm package that is incompatible with RHEL 8 operating system. I made it into a docker image, hoping to run it in a docker way. But I failed. I don't know where the problem lies.

Dockerfile

```
# Dockerfile
FROM centos:7
COPY  mediaserver-1.0.1-12.dev7.x86_64.rpm /opt/
COPY  start_up.sh /opt/
RUN  yum install -y gnutls && yum install -y /opt/mediaserver-1.0.1-12.dev7.x86_64.rpm  \
     && rm -f /opt/mediaserver-1.0.1-12.dev7.x86_64.rpm \
     && yum clean all \
     && rm -rf /var/cache/yum \
     && chmod +x /opt/start_up.sh

WORKDIR /opt/mediaserver

EXPOSE 6001
EXPOSE 17612

ENTRYPOINT ["/bin/bash","-c"]
CMD  sh /opt/start_up.sh
```

start_up.sh

```bash
#!/bin/bash

/etc/init.d/"$program_name" start &

appid=$!

sleep 5

ps aux | grep -q "$program_name"
if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then
  echo "media app failed to start"
  exit 1
fi

echo $appid > /opt/mediaserver/app.pid
exit 0
```

I use `docker run -it`, I can enter the container normally, but the service does not start. I can start it manually.

I use docker run -it, I can enter the container normally, but the service does not start. I can start it manually.

`root     30512     1  0 23:52 ?        00:00:00 /opt/mediaserver/bin/SystemShell -r mediaserver:/opt/mediaserver/bin/mediaserve root     30513 30512  3 23:52 ?        00:00:00 /opt/mediaserver/bin/mediaserver -s mediaserver -m`

Comment: A note: He3lixxx has taken care of this for you, but don't tag a programming language simply because a tool you are using was written in that language. If you are working on the code for that tool, the language tag's probably appropriate, but otherwise you're most likely going to attract the wrong kind of attention.

Answer (score 0):

Your `start_up.sh` requires a variable name `$program_name`, however, you have not defined it anywhere. That's why using `CMD sh /opt/start_up.sh` results Docker container stops at `sh` shell and wait for next instructions.

To fix this, you can either

- Hard code your init script by updating `$program_name` with your application name, for example, if mediaserver start up script is `mediaserver` then replace `$program_name` with `mediaserver`
- Or update your `start_up.sh` to accept an input, then update CMD to something like `CMD sh /opt/start_up.sh mediaserver` (assumed that the program name is `mediaserver`

Answer (score 0):

A Docker container is a wrapper around a single *process*.  The best approach here is to not use any sort of init script, wrapper, or tricks to "keep the container alive"; instead, just run the process in the foreground as the main container `CMD`.

```bash
# (no ENTRYPOINT)
CMD /opt/mediaserver/bin/mediaserver -s mediaserver -m
```

---

The fundamental model of a Docker container is that it runs the single command that comes from combining `ENTRYPOINT` and `CMD`.  When that command exits, the container exits too.

If you read through your script, you run an `init.d` script as a background process, sleep for 5 seconds, maybe write a pid file, and either way `exit`.  This means that the container will *always* exit almost immediately; the background process won't keep running because the main container process has exited.

If you're using this model, you need to do something to cause the main container process to not exit.  The most common workaround is to `sleep infinity`.  Note that this isn't especially connected to the actual process in the container, though: if that `mediaserver` process exits for whatever reason, since the `sleep` command is still running, the container will still stay "alive" as well.

---

Finally: there's a mechanical problem in the interaction between `ENTRYPOINT` and `CMD` as you've shown it.  These work as:

1. If either or both of these is a bare string, wrap them in `sh -c`; then
2. Concatenate the lists of words in `ENTRYPOINT` and `CMD` into a single word list.

Applying those rules, you get the equivalent of

```bash
ENTRYPOINT+CMD ["/bin/bash", "-c", "/bin/sh", "-c", "sh /opt/start_up.sh"]
#               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
#                   ENTRYPOINT     added by Docker           CMD
```

which gets parsed as `/bin/bash -c` interpret and run a command, `/bin/sh` the command to run, `-c 'sh /opt/start_up.sh'` positional parameters to that command starting with `$0`.  That is, this only runs a shell and not your startup script.

You never need to write `["sh", "-c", ...]` in a Dockerfile; the shell form without JSON-array syntax is simpler if you need that.  You also do not need to split the command into its "command" and "arguments", just a single `CMD` line is usually fine.

In short: if you delete the `ENTRYPOINT` line without replacement, your script will actually run.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, there were a few details I didn't mention.
After this mediaserver starts, it seems to exit and bring up two processes to service it.What should I do with it.